# In c++, how can i call derived class using vector?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

i'm coding library program using c++

i declared Book class, derived class magazine, comic book.
i want to print each class function(virtual)
how can i do?

this is main code(declare)

```
vector<Member> MemberInfo;
vector<Book*> BookInfo;

handler.SearchBookInfo(BookInfo);
```

this is handler.cpp(load bookinfo)

```
void Handler::BookLoad(vector<Book*>& book) {
    string loadfile;
    ifstream openfile{"All_in_Book.txt"};

    if(!openfile) {
        cout << "파일을 찾을수 없습니다." << endl;
    }
    else {
        string tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue, comparenum;
        string ilban="a", jap="b", comic="c";
        int counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            openfile>> comparenum >> tmpbookname >> tmpauthor >> tmpisbn >> tmppage >> tmpissue;
            if(comparenum.compare(ilban) == 0)
                book.push_back(new Book(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage));
            else if(comparenum.compare(jap) == 0) {
                book.push_back(new Magazine(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue));
            }
            else if(comparenum.compare(comic) == 0)
                book.push_back(new ComicBook(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue));

            if(openfile.eof()) {
                cout << "총" << counter << "개의 도서 데이터를 불러왔습니다." << endl;
                cout << "아무키나 누르면 종료됩니다." << endl;
                getchar();
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

this is print func

```
void Handler::SearchBookInfo(vector<Book*>& book) { // 일반책만 나오는 문제를 수정해야함.
  for(int i=0; i< book.size(); i++)
      book[i]->ShowBookInfo();
}
```

and this is function in book.cpp

```
class Book { // 기본적인 책의 틀
protected:
    string Book_name, Author, ISBN, PAGE, ISSUE;
public:
    Book(string book_name, string author, string isbn, string page);
    Book() {};
    virtual string GetBookName() const;
    virtual void ShowBookInfo() const;
};

class Magazine : public Book {
public:
    Magazine(string book_name, string author, string isbn, string page, string Magazine_issue);
    Magazine() {};
    virtual string GetBookName() const;
    virtual void ShowBookInfo() const;
}; // 잡지

class ComicBook : public Book{
public:
    ComicBook(string book_name, string author, string isbn, string page, string Comic_issue);
    ComicBook() {};
    virtual string GetBookName() const;
    virtual void ShowBookInfo() const;
}; // 만화
```

if i want to call class Comicbook ShowBookInfo, call ShowBookInfo.
but when i call function(SerachBookInfo), not working.
and i don't know how to call derived class...
is there anyone to help me?

Comment: What do you mean? In `SearchBookInfo`, on each object the method `ShowBookInfo` will be called. Because it's `virtual`, it will be called from the correct object (depending on what was inserted in the `vector`).

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Right now, your code should call `ComicBook::ShowBookInfo` when you call `b->ShowBookInfo` on a `b` of type `Book*` that points to a `ComicBook`. If you don't want that, you can just delete the Method in `ComicBook`, then it will call `Book::ShowBookInfo`. Also: Your Base class has no virtual destructor, hence you will invoke undefined behavior, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). It would also be better to work with `std::unique_ptr<Book>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: i mean i just want to call derived class function. example, if i want to call Book->ShowBookInfo, call ShowBookInfo. or want to call Magazine->ShowBookInfo, call Show Magazine->ShowBookInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code already does what you want. 
When the `ShowBookInfo` method is implemented so that it prints the name of the class

```
virtual void Book::ShowBookInfo() const{ std::cout << "Book\n";}
virtual void Magazine::ShowBookInfo() const{ std::cout << "Magazine\n"; }
virtual void ComicBook::ShowBookInfo() const {std::cout << "ComicBook\n"; }
```

and when three different book types are added the same way as in your `Handler::BookLoad` method

```
void BookLoad(vector<Book*>& book) {
    string tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue, comparenum;
    book.push_back(new Book(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage));
    book.push_back(new Magazine(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue));
    book.push_back(new ComicBook(tmpbookname, tmpauthor, tmpisbn, tmppage, tmpissue));
}
```

then a method that calls `ShowBookInfo` like in your `Handler::SearchBookInfo`

```
void SearchBookInfo(vector<Book*>& book) { 
  for(auto i=0u; i< book.size(); i++)
      book[i]->ShowBookInfo();
}
```

will output the text for the derived class.

```
Book
Magazine
ComicBook
```

See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/577eb4f8fdf27f60).

Comment: feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)